# How to render html page on certain path from certain directory with node.js express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/login.html'));
});
app.get('/views', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/index.html'));
});


// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
// [END app]
```

Rendering the login.html works without any problems. I have index.html in my views directory and am having a hard time rendering index.html. I know should be using app.use somewhere and I've tried that already but I'm not sure how to make this work properly so when I type in localhost:8080/views, index.html should pop up correctly along with everything working in the views folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is usually done with something called [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

The idea is pretty simple :

Let's say you want to render your directory `/views` so that `/views/file1.txt` sends `path.join(__dirname+'/views/file1.txt')` and so on.

You can simply do

```
app.use('/views', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

This will work for any file inside the `/views` directory.

---

**Edit**

Depending on the version of `express` you are using, you might need to take a look at [`serve-static`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) which is the standalone version since `express.static` has been removed.